# Не получается подключаться к серверу с помощью PuTTY

Tags: putty

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, я ввёл неправильный пароль при подключении к серверу через putty и теперь при новом подключении не могу ничего воодить, есть только зелёный курсор, с которым ничего нельзя сделать. Что в таком случае делать?

[[image]

Comment: Вы вводили логин-пароль руками после подключения к серверу или же ввели его в настройках подключения `PuTTy`?

Comment: Вводил руками через консоль putty

Comment: В таком случае, дело  явно на стороне сервера к которому Вы подключаетесь. Как правило там в настройках `sshd` (ssh-сервер) есть параметр отвечающий за макс. кол-во попыток неправильного ввода пароля за какой-то временной отрезок. После чего соединения с данного IP-адреса блокируются на некоторое время. Если у Вас есть контакты администратора сервера попросите его либо перевести Вас на соединение по сертификатам (тогда вводить логин-пароль не нужно), либо добавить Ваш IP-адрес в исключения, чтобы в случае ошибок он не блокировался, либо увеличить значения параметра в настройках `sshd`.

Comment: Спасибо большое!